# How can I fix intermittent iSight camera functionality on a Macbook Pro 5,2?

Tags: webcam, macbook

I have a Macbook Pro 5,2 laptop dual booting OSX and Ubuntu. The built-in iSight video camera works only sporadically.  By that I mean that sometimes if I boot and try to use the camera it does not work (most of the time) but other times it does.  I don't have good repeatable data regarding when it does vs. when it doesn't other than to say that it always seems to work right after I upgrade to a new Linux kernel with the Update Manager and reboot, but then eventually stops working again until I upgrade the kernel again.  That is hard to test repeatably, so it's hard to know for sure that that is the case. This has happened consistently with every version of Ubuntu from 10.10 through 11.10.

I can get around this by booting into the OS/X partition, since all of the hardware obviously works perfectly on that side of things, but it would be great if I could remain in Ubuntu and do the same thing.

Thanks in advance for any inSights.

Answer (score 0):

Have you installed the ppa's yet? They got a pacakage for the iSight, that should work :)

https://launchpad.net/~mactel-support/+archive/ppa

Comment: Have you tried the package Mmmm?